# Why "Guet Nacht!" instead of "Gueti Nacht!" in Schweizerdeutsch

Tags: swiss-german

I often hear "Guet Nacht!" in the evening, whereas I would expect "Gueti Nacht!" as Nacht is feminine. How so?

Comment: I may add that "Gut Nacht" (instead of "Gute Nacht") is also the usual form to wish a good night in Southern Germany. - My explanation would be that, as the term is used so frequently, the suffix "-e" is being ommitted for lazyness (or call it efficiency). Note that you find this also in proverbs: ***Gut Ding will Weile haben*** (instead of "gutes") all over the German speaking part of the world.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Endingless adjective attributes are an archaism. They are preserved in idioms, names, or composites:

- auf gut Glück (instead of: auf gut**es** Glück)
- unser täglich Brot (instead of: unser täglich**es** Brot)
- Gutmensch (instead of: gut**er** Mensch)
- Grossstadt (instead of: gross**e** Stadt)
- gut Nacht (more commonly: gut**e** Nacht)

This is exactly the same in Swiss German, even though some Swiss German adjective endigs differ from their standard German counterparts:

- uf guet Glück (instead of: uf guet**s** Glück)
- Guetmönsch (instead of: guet**e** Mönsch)
- guet Nacht (instead of: guet**i** Nacht)

Note also that some Alemannic dialects (virtually all Swiss German dialects are Alemannic) may have grammaticalized some endingless forms in the paradigm of adjective declension:

- guet Brot (Basel) vs. guet**s** Brot (Berne)/gut**es** Brot (standard German)
- der schön Turm (Berne/Zurich) vs. der schön**i** Turm (Zurich, variant)/der schen**a** Turm (Mulhouse)/der schön**e** Turm (standard German)
- d frisch Milch (Strasbourg) vs. di früsch**i** Milch (Berne)/die frisch**e** Milch (standard German)

I do not know of any Alemannic dialect, though, that would have grammaticalized an endingless form for the strong adjective declension of the feminine singular. With other words, I do not know of any Alemannic dialect where cases like *lieb**i** Sarah* (standard German: *lieb**e** Sarah)* or *guet**i** Nacht* would default to be endingless. Of course, my knowledge is far from complete.

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you for taking the time to answer!